# BigDecimal rounding issue

Tags: java

I want to convert 1256.3648 to 126.36 (up to 2 decimal places)

To implement this thing, I am using `.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));`

But for some reasons, it doesn't work

Any idea?

Comment: Do you mean `126.3648`? Also `BigDecimal` is an immutable type...

Comment: What exactly does not work? What have you already tried?

Comment: [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845937/java-how-to-set-precision-for-double-value)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way

```
.setScale(2, RoundingMode.FLOOR);
```

Assuming you are calling it on the [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) object

will o/p

> 1256.36

If your input is `1256.3648`

> Remember,
>
> `java.math.BigDecimal.setScale(int newScale, RoundingMode
>   roundingMode)` returns a `BigDecimal` whose scale is the specified
>   value, and whose unscaled value is determined by multiplying or
>   dividing this BigDecimal's unscaled value by the appropriate power of
>   ten to maintain its overall value.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a test program demonstrating the rounding:

import java.math.BigDecimal;

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal("1256.3648");
    BigDecimal y = x.setScale(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println(y);
  }
}
```

It outputs:

```
1256.3648
1256.36
```

`x` is unchanged, but the result of the `setScale` call is properly rounded.