# defining decimal places of a double number in Java

Tags: java, double

I have a silly problem.

Let's say I have certain double number:

```
double doubleValue=4.1;
```

Is there a way to present this value as `4.10` but **not** as String but rather as double?

Comment: what is the difference between 4.1 and 4.10?

Comment: Or u wanna output 4.1 as 4.10?

Comment: yes! but not as String! 4.10 should be again a double number

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: How to set Precision for double value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845937/java-how-to-set-precision-for-double-value)

Comment: I dont think it is possible, Since 4.10 mean 4.1 jvm will not gonna store the unnecessary ending 0. Only thing that you can do is format the decimal as a string the way you want

Comment: There's no difference between 4.1 and 4.10. It's the same `double` value.

Comment: The question asked and answer marked as correct doesn't match. Did you wanted a way to represent 4.1 as 4.10 ? @user3133542

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply do this,

```
double doubleValue=4.1;

String.format(Locale.ROOT, "%.2f", doubleValue );
```

Output:

```
4.10
```

Using this approach you don't need to make use of `DecimalFormat` which will also reduce *unnecessary imports*

Comment: Can't guarantee that particular output, as it is locale dependent. e.g. switch to French: `Locale.setDefault(Locale.FRENCH);` before and you will see `4,10`.

Comment: Doesn't answer what was asked. This answer is available everywhere.

Comment: `String.format(Locale.ROOT, "%.2f", doubleValue)` To force a neutral language format.

Comment: @weston thanks for the suggestion, I learned something new too.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to print two decimals do this:

```
double d = 4.10;
 DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
 System.out.print(df.format(d));
```

this will print `4.10` and the number is a double

Here is a fully working example which you can compile and run to print 4.10:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

class twoDecimals {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
double d = 4.10;
 DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
 System.out.print(df.format(d));
}
}
```

even if you set

```
double d = 4.1;
```

it will print `4.10` .

If you set `double d = 4;` it will print 4.00 which means always print two decimal points

Comment: How would it print 4.10? if it sets **.00**??\

Comment: @Apurva That is the format syntax indicating how many digits of precision you want after the decimal point. In this case, it's two.

Comment: Can't guarantee that particular output, as it is locale dependent. e.g. switch to French: `Locale.setDefault(Locale.FRENCH);` before and you will see `4,10`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't define the precision of the data type `double`.
If you need to define the precision of a decimal number you can use the class `BigDecimal`.
As javadoc explains BigDecimal is used for *an arbitrary-precision signed decimal numbers*.
Here is the reference

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why you want double number with 2 digits after decimals with 0 filling the gap. Are you planning to display it somewhere ?

**The Answer is , No, you can't.**

Actually, you can set the precision of a double if it doesn't have any 0 after that.

For ex -

```
4.10000 // and you want to set the precision to 2 digits
// it will still give you 4.1 not 4.10

if it is 4.1 // and you want to set precision to 3 digits
// it will still give you 4.1 not 4.100

if it is 4.1234565 // and you want to set precision to 3 digits,
// it will give you 4.123
```

Even when you format it using String.format and change it back to decimal or use BigDecimal's setScale method to set precision,
you can't get a double value ending with 0 after decimal.

If you want to display with certain decimal somewhere, you can do that by converting into String.

Here are 2 methods to do that, (will set precision but will not set 0 at the end to fill the gap)

1.

```
int numberOfDigitsAfterDecimal = 2;
double yourDoubleResult = 4.1000000000;
Double resultToBeShown = new BigDecimal(yourDoubleResult).setScale(numberOfDigitsAfterDecimal, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).doubleValue();
System.out.println(resultToBeShown);
```

2.

```
double doubleValue=4.1;
double newValue = Double.parseDouble(String.format( "%.2f", doubleValue ));
System.out.println(newValue);
```

For getting 4.10 as string ,

```
double doubleValue=4.1;
String newValue = String.format( "%.2f", doubleValue );
System.out.println(newValue);
```