# how to round the double values with 2 decimal points and store it in Vectors and display?

Tags: java, vector, collections, double, rounding

```
Vector <Double> v=new Vector<Double>();

for (double d=1;d<=50;d++) {
    v.add(d);
    v.add((double)Math.round((d*1.3)*100/100));
}

System.out.println(Math.round((5.255685650*1.3)*100/100));
System.out.println("Multiples of 1.3 is -->"+v);
```

I want the decimal like 45.54 which is stored in vector also.
Please tell me..

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: Why are you using `Vector`? It's 2016, not 1996.

Comment: For your question to set 2 decimal points, it is already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845937/java-how-to-set-precision-for-double-value)!

Comment: You have your closing parenthesis in the wrong place. Try `Math.round((d*1.3)*100)/100` rather than `Math.round((d*1.3)*100/100)`

Comment: i want to store a decimal number which is automatically generated by any mathematical operation or something else. for example 565.5660000000225 like this. so, I want to reduce the decimal points like 565.56 . Then it is stored in to a collection variables (any type of collection doesn't matter it is.) and displays it.. This is what i got problem while practising collections topic.

Answer (score 0):

For example if you have a number with five decimal places that you want to convert to two decimal places:

```
num=45.54345;
num*=100;  // multiply the number by 100 to get 4554.345
num = round(num); // round the number to 4554
num/=100;  // divide the number by 100 to get 45.54
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Use the DecimalFormat  class to format the double values. Please follow the link.

[https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html][1]