# Which primitive data type can be used for saving currency or other precise values, in Java programming language?

Tags: java

Which primitive data type can be used for saving currency or other precise values, in Java programming language? 
Following is a link describing different basic datatypes in Java -
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_datatypes.htm

Comment: None. Use `BigDecimal` instead.

Comment: as said above the primitive types are running into precission loss. you should rather use a BidDecimal as explained in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845937/java-how-to-set-precision-for-double-value) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While many will tell you not to use `double` in fact this is what most investment banks do. Why? Because this is in fact one of the least error prone data types to use.

Why use `double`

- representation is not random errors.
- the precision of double is enough for currencies not experiencing hyper inflation. e.g. the US national debt (which is an estimate anyway) can be represented to 0.1 cent precision. If you have a currency in hyper inflation, don't trade it.
- Using `long` is an option but you need to keep track of the precision correctly or you will accidentally multiply a number by 10x or 100x. This is far worse than adding a 0.000000001 cent.
- Using BigDecimal doesn't mean you don't have to consider rounding, but it does make it hard to detect when you have such an error. It is slower to code and run, and more error prone to write (as it doesn't have language support like C# decimal) e.g. if you see `0.3333333333333332` it's an error but what about `0.33` as a BigDecimal? Looks ok, but it might be `1.00/3`
- A lot of financial libraries are written in C or C++.  These all use `double` as there is no BigDecimal. A good portion of financial trading system are written entirely in C/C++ and they don't use BigDecimal either. (They could use `long long` but most use `double`)

One thing I think everyone agrees on is, don't use `float` unless you have many billions of such values. e.g. for back testing. It has poor precision and the code is actually slightly more verbose.

Comment: Can't decide whether to up- or downvote this. I respect your reasoning, but I'd still go with the wisdom of these answers to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3730019/342852

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd You can argue the theory all you like, but the reality is that banks use C & C++ and they use double. While double has issues, they have less issues in reality.  Having programming with BigDecimal, I have seen it is more error prone having a much more verbose syntax (though I suspect C# decimal is not)  We have OSS libraries used by most big banks in the world and we offer support using `long` and `BigDecimal` as alternatives but AFAIK, no-one uses these alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you want to do, the answer can be either "None" or `long`. In any case, *do not use floating point types for currency values*, so do not use `float` or `double`: they store values in binary, whereas currency values are usually given in decimal, and this means that not all currency values will be stored correctly.

For some purposes you can use `long` to store currency values (you store the number of cents). However, this will limit the size of the values somewhat.

Usually, people use `BigDecimal` to store currency values, but that is not a primitive type (it is part of the Java standard library, however).

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Bigdecimal` to store the decimal value. Also look for [JODA money](http://www.joda.org/joda-money/).

> Joda-Money provides simple value types, representing currency and
>   money.

You can also [look for the reason](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems) as to why you should not use double or other primitive types to store the currency value.

Also note that Java provides a [Currency class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html)

> Represents a currency. Currencies are identified by their ISO 4217
>   currency codes. Visit the ISO web site for more information. The class
>   is designed so that there's never more than one Currency instance for
>   any given currency. Therefore, there's no public constructor. You
>   obtain a Currency instance using the getInstance methods.

Comment: Thanks @Rahul, great information about Currency class and Joda-Money.

Answer (score 1):

If it must be a primitive, there are two strategies:

1. Use `long`, with manual scaling.
2. Use double, but remember the value stored is a very close approximation to the actual value. Often, people forget how close. It is precise enough to store the US Nation Debt to the nearest cent.

Of course, the best solution is to forget about the "primitive" requirement and use BigDecimal, which was designed for exact storage of decimal fractions.