# What will be the format of the double

Tags: java

I have a one function `i.e applyCredit(double amount )`

if i am calling this function as `applyCredit(inputAmount)`

and `inputAmount` is in double 2 precision format `i.e ####.00` if the `amount` in a function got updated several times

and now question is : format of the `amount` always will be with 2 precision or it may get changed as it is of the type `double`

Comment: `inputAmount` cannot be in a specific format. Format is for display purposes only. A double doesn't store format information.

Comment: So do u mean if we format the variable and try to save that it will not store in the format as given 
it will store the original value right ?

Comment: Please take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21596413/6505091). That (`BigDecimal`) should do the trick, if you want to have control over the precision.

Comment: You should not use floating point numbers for currency, as some values can not be represented precisely and you may get odd rounding errors. Better use integer/long (in cents)

Comment: You don't "format the variable". Any formatting returns a string, not a double. Formatting is not applied inside a double.

Comment: @m0skit0 after formatting i m type - casting that result to store

Comment: @Nutan Sorry I don't understand what you mean with "typecasting that result to store".

Comment: @m0skit0 type -casting mean i m converting that string into double and then storing in the database

Comment: Why are converting back and forth from/to string to store? Why not store as double?

Comment: @m0skit0 as it is the amount ...i m getting it in 5 precision and want to store it in 2 precision by doing the rounding of that 5 precision

Answer (score 0):

As long as it can "fit in" the input can be with or without decimals

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(applyCredit(2));
    System.out.println(applyCredit(2.66));
    System.out.println(applyCredit(2.72251));
}
static private double applyCredit(double amount ){
    return amount*2;
}
```

will print :
4.0 , 5.32 , 5.44502