# Java inflation calculator problem not rounding correctly

Tags: java, calculator

Prompt: It is difficult to make a budget that spans several years, because prices are not stable.
If your company needs 200 pencils per year, you cannot simply use this years price
as the cost of pencils two years from now. Because of inflation, the cost is likely to
be higher than it is today. Write a program to gauge the expected cost of an item in
a specified number of years. The program asks for the cost of the item, the number
of years from now that the item will be purchased, and the rate of inflation. The
program then outputs the estimated cost of the item after the specified period.
Have the user enter the inflation rate as a percentage, such as 5.6 (percent). Your
program should then convert the percent to a fraction, such as 0.056 and should
use a loop to estimate the price adjusted for inflation.

Code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.text.NumberFormat;

    public class InflationCalculator {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
     
           Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
   
           System.out.print("Enter price of the Item:");
           double cost = console.nextDouble();
    
           System.out.print("Enter number of years in which it will be purchased:");
           double years = console.nextDouble();
    
           System.out.print("Enter percent of inflation per year:");
           double inflationRate = console.nextDouble();       
     
           inflationRate = inflationRate / 100;
   
           for(int i = 1; i <= years; i++){
           cost += cost * inflationRate;
        }
   
      System.out.println(cost);
     }   
 }
```

Expected Result:

Enter·price·of·the·Item:200↵
Enter·number·of·years·in·which·it·will·be·purchased:50↵
Enter·percent·of·inflation·per·year:5↵
2293.479957150**7338**↵

What I got :

Enter·price·of·the·Item:200↵
Enter·number·of·years·in·which·it·will·be·purchased:50↵
Enter·percent·of·inflation·per·year:5↵
2293.479957150**734**↵

I'm not sure why it is not rounding correctly, what did I do wrong ???

Comment: precision when using floats and doubles can be a tricky thing.  For such a purpose Java language suggests using the BigDecimal datatype that is good for this sort of situation.

look into Currency class in javalang.

Comment: you have to use BigDecimal instead of Double. It's difficult to calculate decimal numbers with precision.

Comment: Using BigDecimal made it worse unfortunately

Comment: what do you mean with "worse"? Show us the output

Answer (score 2):

This code should work well:

```
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter price of the Item:");
    BigDecimal cost = new BigDecimal(console.nextDouble());

    System.out.print("Enter number of years in which it will be purchased:");
    int years = console.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter percent of inflation per year:");
    BigDecimal inflationRate = new BigDecimal(console.nextDouble());

    inflationRate = inflationRate.divide(new BigDecimal(100));
    
    for(int i = 1; i <= years; i++) {
        cost = cost.add(cost.multiply(inflationRate));
    }

    System.out.println(cost);
```

The output (using your inputs): `2293.4799571507352069702827102422103183593712979003728316020223783073817003241856582462787628173828125000`

If you want to round this number to your expected result, you can use

```
System.out.println(cost.setScale(10, BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING)); // to round up
// or
System.out.println(cost.setScale(10, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR)); // to round down
```

The first parameter of .setScale() is the number of decimal digit that you want to show up. (sorry for my bad english lol)

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**

The `double` variable type has a precision of about [15-16 decimal points](https://www.educba.com/java-float-vs-double/). This is why your result is being truncated.

**Solution:**

You can instead use `BigDecimal` or `DecimalFormat`, as explained in [these answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845937/java-how-to-set-precision-for-double-value)